# Analytical parameters for a 3x3 orthogonal transformation matrix

Tags: group-theory, linear-algebra

A given orthogonal transformation can be generally expressed by a orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{U}$ for which $\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$ parameters are required.
For 2-dimensional systems, U is simply given by the following one-parameter-based transformation
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{U}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The parameter for which $\mathbf{U}$ diagonalizes a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix $\mathbf{B}$ is given by inforcing the out of diagonal element of the transformed matrix $\mathbf{B}'$ to be zero, namely
\begin{equation}
B_{12}'=0~~~~~\text{where}~~~~~~\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{B}\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{B}'
\end{equation}
The parameter can be obtained simply by inverting the following relation
\begin{equation}
\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2B_{12}}{B_{11}-B_{22}}
\end{equation}
For a 3-dimensional system 3 parameters (say $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$) are required for representing a orthogonal transformation. 
Is there an analytical expression for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ that makes a general symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix diagonal?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Eulers angles are indeed ratios of the vertex projection. To rearrange a matrix to a diagonal is the assumption of othogonality and thus all the angles are one quarter.

Comment: I haven't gotten the chance to check it throughly, but this might be what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Higher_dimensions

Comment: I havent done it, but I would try to.use quarternions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation there is a mapping between rotations and quarternions (see quartenion derived rotation matrix section). But I dont know.if it can be done.

Comment: I misread yourquestion diagonalizing symmetric matrices might be more difficult

Comment: This seems to be purely a question about mathematics. What makes it a question about physics?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am posting this question in the Physics forum simply because I believe that I have more chances to get an answer to the problem since many physicists are interested in the standard model and may have been interested in the Cabibbo–Kobayashi–Maskawa matrix, which is closely realted to this issue.

Comment: @Tyberius The wiki link is the starting point I would start from: given the matrix parametrized with respect to the 3 Euler´s angles, one has to transform a general 3x3 symmetric matrix and impose the tre upper out diagonal terms equal to zero; this namely means to solve a system of 3 equations that looks not really friendly.